# Or equal (|=) ; And equal (&=);

Tags: c++, logical-operators

I've been coding in c++ for quite a while. today I've stumbled upon one table. it was depicting Logical operators and their symbols. Till now all of the operators I've ever used were : && , || , !. However the table tells that there are more. I haven't really cared about them except for two: "OR EQUAL" and "AND EQUAL".I have searched the internet for them. Sadly found no proper results.
Here is a picture of the table and  code below showing my point of view how those two operators could work.

[image]

Have you ever used these operators, if so how?

Comment: Look up bitwise operators.  That will cover `|`. `&`, and `^` along with their `=` coutnerparts.

Comment: That table has about the most wrong "description" of the operators I've ever seen.  The correct search term you are looking for is **compound assignment**.  They do *not* perform equality testing like `!=` (NOT EQUAL TO) does.

Comment: And throw that learning resource away and never look at it again.